# Kafka Connect - Connector with same Kafka cluster as a source?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I only found references to MirrorMaker v2.

Can I reuse `org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector` as if it were a "plain" Connector with Kafka as a source, or is there something else, hopefully simpler, available?

I'm trying to use KafkaConnect and (a combination of) its SMTs to simulate message routing behaviour found in other message brokers.

For example, I would like to consume from a topic, extract values from the message (either headers or payload), and route the message to another topic *within* the same cluster depending on the data found in the message.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> within the same cluster

Then that's what Kafka Streams or ksqlDB are for. You can import and use SMT methods directly via code, although you also need to use the Connect Converter classes to get Schema/Struct types that most of the SMT's require

While you could use MirrorMaker, intercluster relocation is not its purpose